# I made a game and I put a skybox or simply box but when I start game the camera isn't displaying it

Tags: game-engine, objects, camera, normals

[image: When I start the game or press <kbd>P</kbd> it doesn't display the cube]
When I start the game or press <kbd>P</kbd> it doesn't display my big brow sky cube.

Comment: The big cube/box with brown color isn't displaying in the game when I start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Very simple reason why your sky box is not displaying. The reason for this is that you did not reverse the normals on your cube.

If you enable *Backface Culling* and set the normals to display,

[image]

You will notice that your normals are pointing outward. This means that you can see them from the outside.

If you reverse the normals, (Select the faces that are pointing the wrong way and click *Flip Normals*

[image]

it will make the normals point inward.

[image]

Now you are seeing through the faces pointing inward to the other side.
If you were inside the cube, you will see all the faces properly.

Comment: Que easy button from staples.

Comment: I was amazed that it stayed Un-answered for 5 hours.- It was pretty much an insta-answer for me...

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I don't see the "Mesh Display" thing?

Comment: I dont see it below the "Shading"

Comment: Oh sorry for my noobness it was in edit mode