# Seeing through objects in Game engine

Tags: game-engine, normals, sculpting

I used sculpting on a plane, and things looks great. However, when I press <kbd>P</kbd> to play, the whole ground become a mess. I can see through it in various places, and there are also nasty looking black edges everywhere.

another problem, I made a UV Sphere to display the sky, but when I press , <kbd>P</kbd> to play it disappears!

[image]

Comment: you may want to turn down specularity on your sand, it won't solve your problem, but it'll look more real.

Comment: it caused because backface culling is off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is very simple to fix. your normals are reversed.

You can easily see which faces are pointing inward by enabling ***Backface Culling***. This enables you to see though the back of faces like you do when you press <kbd>P</kbd>.

[image]

You could also enter edit mode on that object, and enable the normals visualization.

[image]

On high-polly models such as this one, this may or may not help much.

to fix this you could manually go though and select each face that is pointing the wrong way, and flip the normals by pressing the  <kbd>Flip Normals</kbd>  button.

[image]

You Could also select all of your faces and press the  <kbd>Recalculate</kbd>  button, to recalculate the normals. This sometimes works, and sometimes it makes it worse. It is a good idea to try this first, because there is always <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for the times when it does not work.

In this case, it made all of the normals point the same way, but then they were all pointing the wrong direction. Simply flipping all of them could fix this easily enough. Sometimes more complex objects can confuse blender and recalculate them quite wrong.

[image]

## For your sky object, see  [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28199/5426)

Comment: i wonder how the sculpting caused this.?

Comment: No idea why....