# How do I fix the Problem With Half my Object disappearing?

Tags: modeling, rendering, game-engine

I am having a slight problem with a moon rover I am creating for a game. When I try to render it (in Blender Game) half the object disappears, or becomes hollow.
Here is a picture from camera perspective of the Object in editor:

[image: Rover in Blender not rendered]

Here is a picture when I press <kbd>P</kbd> to start the Engine:

[image: Rendered Rover]

I am currently using Blender Version 2.74
How can I fix this Error?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the face normals are facing the wrong way. Select the object that produces error, go into edit mode, select all with A and recalculate normals with CTRL+N.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Edit Mode of your Object. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the Properties panel in 3D View. Go to the heading named "Mesh Display" and activate the "Face Normals" Button. Now you can see the Faces and their orientation.
Faces in the Game Engine that point into your Mesh (away from the camera) are rendered invisible.

The length of the blue Face normal indicator can be changed. If it is too short you may not see the Face normal. If it is too long you may think the Face is pointing outwards but instead its the Face of the opposite side and its Normal is so long that it goes through other Faces.

The length of the Normal indicator doesn't have an influence on Graphics. Its only for you to see its direction. Just choose a length you can work with.

Sometimes its just a few of them pointing inwards and sometimes the Option "Recalculate Normals" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) doesn't work properly. Then you just select the Faces you want to flip and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and then <kbd>F</kbd> again. Your selected Faces are flipped and the Problem should be solved.

Comment: How is this any different from what [I said in my answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30938/5426)?

Comment: Good answer! I just didn't notice it at the time i was answering. ;)