# Walls aren't appearing right in game mode

Tags: mesh, game-engine

When I built the walls of my scene, I did it by creating many subdivides and extruding up to create an entire building using a single plane. The problem is, it looks fine in obj/and edit mode, but when I enter game mode, my walls become paper thin and I phase through them even with collision active. Any idea why this is happening? [image]

[image]

Comment: Check your normals. - this question should help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/30916/5426

Comment: Thank you very much. That solution worked. Just had to flip my normals.